# How export fetch data to another module

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, ecmascript-6, module

I have two modules, module.js and controller.js, in module I have:

```
export class Module {
    constructor(){
        const fetchParams = {
            method: "GET",
            mode: "cors",
            cache: "default"
        };
        const url = 'https://swapi.co/api/people/';
         fetch(url, fetchParams)
            .then(res => {
                if(!res.ok){
                    throw new Error(res.statusText);
                }
                return res.json();
            })
            .then(data => {
                const characters = data.results;
                this.characters = characters;
            })
    }
}
```

in controller I have:

```
import {Module} from "./module";
class Controller extends Module{
    constructor(){
        super();
    }

    checkData(){
           console.log(this.characters);
    }
}
```

In checkData() I have undefined, how can I wait for the answer from the module first, and only then get it in checkData()
PS: Im using webpack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Module`, move the fetch call to a separate method, then have the child class call that method, so it can attach a `.then` to the promise and wait for its completion (and handle errors). If you're interested in making the code look a little cleaner, [look into using async/await syntax.](https://javascript.info/async-await)

```
class Module {
  constructor() {
    this.characters = []
  }

  fetchCharacters() {
    const fetchParams = {
      method: "GET",
      mode: "cors",
      cache: "default",
    }

    const url = "https://swapi.co/api/people/"

    // IMPORTANT: return the promsie from fetch, so that callers can use it
    return fetch(url, fetchParams)
      .then(res => {
        if (!res.ok) {
          throw new Error(res.statusText)
        }
        return res.json()
      })
      .then(data => {
        const characters = data.results
        this.characters = characters
      })
  }
}

class Controller extends Module {
  checkData() {
    return this.fetchCharacters().then(() => {
      console.log(this.characters)
    })
  }
}

new Controller().checkData()
```